# Android Google Maps infowinfow arrow not centered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I just noticed that the arrow below my infowindow slightly off-centered is. It is like 5dp moved to the left. I am using the code from the google example and didn't change anything. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: You may used `map padding`, cancel that should be fine.

Comment: What is map padding?